# In Ruby the aws-sdk gem, is it ok to pass a nil value for a parameter?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In the Ruby aws-sdk gem, is it ok to pass a nil value for a parameter, if the parameter is not required?

I want to do

```
s3_client.list_objects(bucket: bucket_name,  prefix: path_to_files, marker: marker)
```

and I want to know if it's ok, for the first `list_objects` request, to have a `marker` value of `nil` (which is the same as `marker: nil`). Or do I have to do `s3_client.list_objects(bucket: bucket_name,  prefix: path_to_files)` without `marker: marker` if `marker` is nil?

The documentation has

> `:marker` (`String`) — Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket.

so I know that `:marker` is not required, but is passing in a `nil` value supported behaviour (after all, it's not a `String`), and is it guaranteed to give the same results as not passing in a value at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for aws-sdk-v1 and doing a project search for `:marker` shows where they use this parameter key, it seems to be guarded by checks to see if its non falsy. So I'd assume it's safe to pass in nil in this case. More specifically, the definition for the `list_objects` method in `lib/aws/s3/client.rb`:

```
# @overload list_objects(options = {})
      #   @param [Hash] options
      #   @option options [required,String] :bucket_name
      #   @option options [String] :delimiter
      #   @option options [String] :marker
      #   @option options [String] :max_keys
      #   @option options [String] :prefix
      #   @return [Core::Response]
      bucket_method(:list_objects, :get, XML::ListObjects) do
        configure_request do |req, options|
          super(req, options)
          params = %w(delimiter marker max_keys prefix)
          params.each do |param|
            if options[param.to_sym]
              req.add_param(param.gsub(/_/, '-'), options[param.to_sym])
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

Notice how every parameter is checked for falsiness before being added to the request `if options[param.to_sym]`. However, I didn't check to see if aws actually requires this param.

So try it. Does it work without `:marker`? If so, and the results are as expected, then it's safe to use nil there. Indeed, it would be exactly the same as not passing it in at all, since, according to the above implementation, the `add_param` method is only called if it's non falsy.